# Dependency cycle frustrations

Tags: drivers

I often see `Dependency cycle detected` console errors, but have innocently ignored them as I feel there is an arcane technical language behind the references such as:

```
Dependency cycle detected:
  OBMBLab_skeleton_face_rig.MBlab_YoungMale/DRIVER(pose.bones["Expressions_eyeClosedL_max.L"].location) depends on
  OBMBLab_skeleton_face_rig.MBlab_YoungMale/Expressions_eyeClosedL_max.L/BONE_LOCAL() via 'RNA Target -> Driver'
  OBMBLab_skeleton_face_rig.MBlab_YoungMale/DRIVER(pose.bones["Expressions_eyeClosedL_max.L"].location) via 'Driver -> Driven Property'
```

...okay: location is location, but is RNA like DNA?  This information is probably useful to the more-experienced blend python programmer.

I look at the driver editor and I don't see my location driver dependent on it's location:

[image]

so I cannot comprehend and unfortunately am not finding sufficient answers in this forum.

I'm including a simple blend file, where I'm trying to drive a characters blinking of each eye by a single animated custom property.  [image]

While this error doesn't seem to affect a working solution I had to back out a dependency cycle in another file yesterday where the [program kept crashing](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/111120) (again I could not figure out the longer list of circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the custom property, but with the variable referencing the constraint parameters, a constraint which exists on the same bone.

Constraints are evaluated on top of-- after-- the driver providing the location of the bone.  The precise action of a limit location constraint depends on the location of the bone going into the constraint.  In general terms, we can't drive the transform of a bone from details of its constraints, because its constraints depend on the transform of the bone.

Now, in this case, the minimum Z parameter of the constraint isn't technically dependent on the transform of the bone-- it's just an arbitrary, user-provided field.  But Blender isn't perfectly granular in its treatment of dependencies.  To Blender, it's part of the action of a constraint, and *some* parts of a constraint depend on bone location, so all parts of a constraint depend on bone location.

Since this isn't a true dependency loop, just a failing of Blender's division of dependencies, we can work around it.  We'll make a new custom property for the bone and drive both our existing driver and our Limit Location's min Z from this custom property:

[image]

RNA and DNA are just terms used internally in Blender to refer to different types of data.  The RNA here refers to the details of your constraint, which is being accessed by a "single property" type variable.  Notice the double helix icon for the driver variable.  (Which is kinda weird, RNA doesn't do double helix, and drivers don't reference DNA, the blueprint for individual RNA objects.)  I wouldn't worry too hard about the precise messages given for the dependency cycle warnings, and focus instead on trying to just trace through the properties that Blender thinks are dependent on each other.  But yes, that can be difficult at times.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that concise and clear explanation!  That worked for me.